# Updating webbrowser content with SVG

Tags: xml, vb.net, svg, webbrowser-control

I am using a webbrowser control to display an SVG file created in my program and saved in a public variable as XMLdocument. Now I want to edit my SVG and load the new file in the webbrowser control.

this is my the variable I am using

```
Public XSchemaSVG As New XmlDocument
```

And when I populate it and load it in my webbrowers everything works then when I want an updated version I use the following code to reload the SVG

```
  Public Sub DrawSVGinWebBrowserControl()

    Dim text As String = XSchemaSVG.InnerXml
    WebBrowser1.DocumentText = "<!DOCTYPE HTML><html><head><meta http-equiv=""x-ua-compatible"" content=""IE=11""><meta http-equiv=""Content-Type"" content=""text/html; charset=utf-8""><title>SVG overzicht</title> </head><body>" & text & "</body></html>"

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'Clear XSchemaSVG
    XSchemaSVG.RemoveAll()
    'Draw new SVG in XSchemaSVG
    DrawOverzichtSVG()
    'load new SVG in webbrowser control 
    DrawSVGinWebBrowserControl()

End Sub
```

But the picture in the webbrowser control doesnt change. I think it has either something to do with the way I clear the XMLdocument or the way I load it in the webbrowser control, can anyone help me out here and tell me what I am doing wrong? and how to fix it?

Edit: So I checked and I can validate that my XMLdocument is getting updated. so the problem lies in the reloading of the webbrowser control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem by using the following code on the DrawSVGinwebbrowser sub

```
  Public Sub DrawSVGinWebBrowserControl()

    Dim text As String = XSchemaSVG.InnerXml
    WebBrowser1.DocumentText = "0"
    WebBrowser1.Document.OpenNew(True)
    WebBrowser1.Document.Write("<!DOCTYPE HTML><html><head><meta http-equiv=""x-ua-compatible"" content=""IE=11""><meta http-equiv=""Content-Type"" content=""text/html; charset=utf-8""><title>SVG overzicht</title> </head><body>" & text & "</body></html>")
    WebBrowser1.Refresh()

End Sub
```